# DatabaseCleaner doesn't seem to clean between suits

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, database-cleaner

saviors.

I'm having a trouble with cleaning database after each RSpec example.
The thing is, that when I run `rspec` command, users_controller_spec.rb complains that there are more records than the example expects. Indeed the records are being created as it says if I check with `rails c`.
when I run the this suite alone, it will be successful, so I assume it is because DatabaseCleaner doesn't clean the user records which other specs create(the number of user records matches the extra records users_controller_spec example claims to be). They are created in `before :all` block(if that matters).

Here is my `rails_helper.rb`

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require 'spec_helper'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'

# Add additional requires below this line. Rails is not loaded until this point!
require 'devise'
require 'admin/v1/dashboard_controller'
# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc, in
Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }

# Checks for pending migrations before tests are run.
# If you are not using ActiveRecord, you can remove this line.
ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :controller
  config.include ControllerMacros, type: :controller
  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods

  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.around(:each) do |example|
    DatabaseCleaner.cleaning do
      example.run
    end
  end
end
```

`users_controller.rb`

```
describe 'GET #index' do
  it 'populates an array of users' do
    user1 = create(:user)
    user2 = create(:user)
    get :index
    expect(assigns(:users)).to match_array([user1, user2])
  end
  it 'renders :index template' do
    get :index, {}
    expect(response).to render_template :index
  end
end
```

UPDATE1: this is where the extra `user` records are created

```
    require 'rails_helper'

describe Admin::V1::MessagesController do
  let(:admin_user) do
    admin_user = double('admin_user')
    allow(request.env['warden']).to receive(:authenticate!).and_return(admin_user)
    allow(controller).to receive(:current_admin_v1_admin_user).and_return(admin_user)
    p '==='
  end
  before { login_admin_user admin_user }

  describe 'GET #index' do
    it 'renders :index template' do
      get :index, {}
      expect(response).to render_template :index
    end
  end

  describe 'GET #get_users' do
    before :all do
      @user1 = create(:user, nickname: 'hiro')
      @user2 = create(:user, nickname: 'elise')
    end
    context 'with params' do
      it 'populates an array of users matching on nickname' do
        get :get_users, format: :json, query: 'h'
        expect(assigns(:users)).to match_array([@user1])
      end
    end
    context 'without params' do
      it 'populates an array of all users' do
        get :get_users, format: :json
        expect(assigns(:users)).to match_array([@user1, @user2])
      end
    end
  end

  describe 'GET #get_messages' do
    before :all do
      @user1 = create(:user)
      @user2 = create(:user)
      @message1 = create(:message, user_id: @user1.id)
      @message2 = create(:message, user_id: @user1.id)
      @message3 = create(:message, user_id: @user2.id)
    end
    context 'with user_id' do
      it 'populates an array of messages with the user_id' do
        get :get_messages, format: :json, user_id: @user1.id
        expect(assigns(:messages)).to match_array([@message1, @message2])
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Your configuration looks ok. There might be an error in other specs (not in *users_controller_apec.rb*). How many specs do you have? Try executing specs in groups to find out where records created.

Comment: I have 8 controller specs at the moment. And the extra records are being created in examples where frontend javascript ajaxes user info and as api rails retrieves some user records(hence user records factoried).

Comment: Could you show these specs? (add them to your question)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately RSpec's `before(:all)` does not play nicely with transactional tests. The code in `before(:all)` gets run before the transaction is opened, meaning any records created there will not be rolled back when the transaction is aborted. You are responsible for manually cleaning these items up in an `after(:all)`.

See [rspec-rails#496](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/496) and [Using before(:all) in RSpec will cause you lots of trouble unless you know what you are doing](https://makandracards.com/makandra/11507-using-before-all-in-rspec-will-cause-you-lots-of-trouble-unless-you-know-what-you-are-doing)

```
  after(:all) do
    # before/after(:all) is not transactional; see https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/transactions
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked! Never thought there would be this clean and logical answer. After all, documentation rules..

Comment: Nice, glad it helped!